# Algebraic structure question

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Suppose there exist subgroups $H,K\subseteq G$ such that $G = H \cup K$. Prove that $H = G$ or $K = G$.

I am not sure how to start?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sorry, hadn't seen that.

Answer (score 2):

If one of $H,K$ contains the other we are done.  Otherwise, let $h\in H$ but $h \notin K$, and $k \in K$ but $k \notin H$.  Then $hk$ is in $G=H\cup K$ so it is in $H$ or $K$.  Suppose it is in $H$.  Then $k=h^{-1}hk \in H$, contradicting choice of $k$.  Similarly we have a contradiction if $hk\in K$.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $H$ and $K$ are proper subgroups of $G$. Fix some $a\in G\backslash H$ and $b\in G\backslash K$. Consider the element $ab$. If $ab\in H$, then multiplying on the right by $b^{-1}$ shows that $a\in H$, a contradiction. A similar argument with $a^{-1}$ shows that $ab\in K$ leads to a contradiction. So the hypothesis is impossible.

Comment: That should be "... shows that $a \in H$".

Comment: @DustanLevenstein Thanks, I corrected it.